# 4.6.2 Library Appears to Be Referenced but Cannot be Resolved in Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have been messing with the new .NET Core 1.1 and am trying to get a dll written in .NET 4.6.2 resolved. I added the project **TestLibrary** as a project reference in the project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net462": {
      "dependencies": {
        "TestLibrary": {
          "target": "project"
        }

      }
    },

...
```

This appears to load the assembly:

[image: Loaded Assembly]

Intellisense seems to recognize the assembly:

[image: Recognize]

But, I am getting a compilation error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The full project.json is below:

```
{
  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {
      "dependencies": {
        "TestLibrary": {
          "target": "project"
        }

      }
    },
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.1.0",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

The full class I am using to test is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening here and how do I resolve it?

Comment: This seems like it would be helpful: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie The line in the article: `some people don't realize that ASP.NET Core 1.0 (that's the web framework bit) runs on either .NET Core or .NET Framework 4.6` really did help. I didn't realize that and didn't realize I could remove the Core Reference from my frameworks list :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message says it.

Your application target `net462` and `netcoreapp1.1`. But your library only targets `net462`, that's why the `netcoreapp1.1` can't find the class.

You either have to target `netstandard1.x` in your `TestLibrary` (if you don't use any `net462` only APIs which may not be available in `netstandard1.x` or you remove `netcoreapp1.1` and only target the full .NET Framework (and not .NET Core).

#### Some background information

When you have more than 1 target in the framework section, then Visual Studio (and the `dotnet build`) will build **multiple** executable files, **one per target**. Your `TestLibrary` fulfills the requirement for `net462` target, but it doesn't for `netcoreapp1.1`, because `netcoreapp1.1` doesn't reference this library.

#### Update

If for example you want to use some functions which is only available on one plattform (i.e. [PerfCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx)), then you would reference this library in `net462` and use it only in binary which compile for `net462` and remove it from `netcoreapp1.1`

```
#if NET462
    var perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Category", 
        "CounterName", 
        false);
    // do something with it here
#endif
```

Now you can use it as extra feature in `net462` and the .NET Core version (`netcoreapp1.1`) won't have it included, because this API is unavailable in .NET Core 1.1.

Comment: I think this is what I would have to do in this case. At the moment, there is no way to reference old dlls that use their own APIs in the core framework?

Comment: If you want to use a class, all targets need to reference it. Often you would use replacement library with same API or use `#if` preprocessor directives to use one code or the other

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: Added a sample which demonstrates when and why you would to use a certain library/package in only one of the targets